# apache ignite java thin client expired entry listener

Tags: java, ignite

Apache Ignite supports ContinuousQuery and local listener for entry events like **create**, **put**, **delete**. But when I try to listen for expired entry event it does not work.
There code example for reproduce [java thin client example](https://github.com/Vichukano/ignite-thin-client-listener-example/blob/main/src/main/java/ru/vichukano/ignite/server/IgniteServer.java).

If change event type to CREATED it's work as expected:

> ```
> query.setRemoteFilterFactory((Factory<CacheEntryEventFilter<Integer, String>>) () -> e -> e.getEventType().equals(EventType.CREATED));
> ```

Does ignite java thin client supports local listener for **Expired** entry event type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure listening for the `EXPIRED` event explicitly with

```
query.setIncludeExpired(true)
```

According to [JavaDoc](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/AbstractContinuousQuery.html#setIncludeExpired-boolean-):

> Sets the flag value defining whether to notify about EventType.EXPIRED
> events. If true, then the remote listener will get notifications about
> entries expired in cache. Otherwise, only EventType.CREATED,
> EventType.UPDATED and EventType.REMOVED events will be fired in the
> remote listener. This flag is false by default, so EventType.EXPIRED
> events are disabled.

Comment: Thanks, I try this in my code example, but its does not work anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? I just added this line to your code and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Can you update the GitHub sources with setIncludeExpired(true)?

Comment: Updated sources: [link](https://github.com/Vichukano/ignite-thin-client-listener-example/blob/main/src/main/java/ru/vichukano/ignite/server/IgniteServer.java#L35)

After update only created event appears:
`-----------CACHE POPULATED---------------
EVENT: CREATED 2 two
EVENT: CREATED 3 three
EVENT: CREATED 1 one
[13:06:14] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:20.812]`
`
-----------CACHE POPULATED---------------
EVENT: CREATED 2 two
EVENT: CREATED 3 three
EVENT: CREATED 1 one
[13:06:14] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:20.812]

Comment: Thanks, now I see. This is because you close the client implicitly when the main loop exits try-block. If a client is destroyed, there is nobody to inform about events. Just remove `try` block and you'll get the events.